# PhoneGap Android Error-Message: 9 while fetching the SD Card

Tags: android, cordova

i bought the book "apress beginning phonegap" but some examples doesnt work.
on this example iam trying to fetch content of my SDCard with phoneGap on my android device.
but i get an -> `error.message : 9` back.
i am a complete newbie in mobile development, and thats the reason i have no idea what could be wrong.

```
function onDeviceReady() {

 window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI("file:///sdcard",onResolveSuccess, onError);

}

function onResolveSuccess(fileEntry) {

    var directoryReader = fileEntry.createReader();
    directoryReader.readEntries(onSuccess, onError);
}

function onSuccess(entries) {

    document.getElementById("loading").innerHTML = "";
    var ul = document.getElementById("file-listing");
    for (var index = 0; index < entries.length; index++) {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = entries[index].name;
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
}

function onError(error) {

    alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n'+ 'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

/** Called when browser load this page*/

function init(){

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}
```

where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you are missing the write external storage permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file. Try adding:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and I'm willing to bet your problem goes away.

Alright, since that did not fix your problem you may want to look at trying to request the url of file:///mnt/sdcard as /sdcard can be a sym link a lot of the times.

Howerver, you would be better served by doing a:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onSuccess, onError);
```

and your success callback will give you a fileSystem who's root property is a directory entry and on Android this would be your SD card.

Comment: ups. no it has nothing to do with it because <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> was added, while i tried to fetch the sdcard listing.

Answer (score 0):

ON Emulator:
In my case the avd device that I created had no sdcard storage, so it failed, I created an sdcard size on the avd proprieties and that fixed the issue on the emulator.

On Physical Device: 
Try to access your sdcard thru another program and see if that works, if not your sdcard may be defective or have failed.